# Which of several ways to set the caps for an appsrc is good and proper these days?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm writing experimental gstreamer apps in C++ on Linux.  In attempting to create an appsrc to emit algorithmically generated frames, I found online several ways to set the appsrc's source pad caps.  I assume some are obsolete. Some may be for the old gst 0.1 and not to be used. I find example code that's not labelled as to gstreamer version. It's a jumble. Most of the ways I found can be summarized in this gob of code:

```
    source = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc",  "MyAwesomeSource");

#if (1)
  #if (1)
    auto caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", 
//  auto caps = gst_video_format_new_caps("video/x-raw", 
                    "format",  G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
                    "width",  G_TYPE_INT,     FrameWidth,
                    "height",  G_TYPE_INT,     FrameHeight,
                    "framerate",  GST_TYPE_FRACTION, framerate, 1, 
                    "interlace-mode", G_TYPE_STRING, "progressive",
                    nullptr);
  #else
    auto caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw-rgb",
          "bpp",G_TYPE_INT,24,
          "depth",G_TYPE_INT,24,
          "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
          "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
          NULL);                        
  #endif 
#else
    GstVideoInfo vi;
    gst_video_info_set_format(&vi, GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_RGBx, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
    auto caps = gst_video_info_to_caps(&vi);
#endif
    g_object_set(source, "caps",  caps,
       ...
```

I'm looking for a clear explanation of what's the proper, correct way to do this in gstreamer-1.0, along with understanding of why the other ways are not as good. Some details I'd like addressed: what's the difference between video/x-raw and video/x-raw-rgb  when there's already a "format" property set to "RGB".   And is the "x" in "RGBx" literal, a place holder for an optional "A" for alpha channel, or a placeholder for "8", "16" or some such number of bits per channel, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is the second option (gst_caps_new_simple(..)) [caps](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstCaps.html)

video/x-raw-rgb is the old style (0.10-style) of setting the caps from 
Gstreamer-1.0 video/x-raw,format=(string) should be used ([supported media types](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/media-types.html#list-of-defined-media-types) also "gst-inspect-1.0  | grep typefindfunctions" should list). And "x" in "RGBx" literal is not a place holder its just the notion how media type was defined.